# Migrate different content types from other CMS

Tags: migrations

I want to migrate content from a non-Drupal CMS to Drupal 8 using the Migration API. In the source CMS, I have different types of content that I have to map to Drupal 8 content types. The navigation needs to be migrated, too. Thats a task, I already finished. During the process, I create a page type for every menu_link_content like so:

```
# Migration configuration
id: navigation_main
label: Main navigation
migration_group: test

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: json
  urls: 'http://my.url.com/migrate/structure?start=841'
  item_selector: data
  fields:
    -
      name: tid
      label: 'Unique element id'
      selector: tid
    -
      name: nav_title
      label: 'Element title'
      selector: nav_title
    -
      name: path
      label: 'ID Path from root down to given id'
      selector: path
    -
      name: parent_tid
      label: 'Parent id'
      selector: parent_tid
    -
      name: elementtype_unique_id
      label: 'Elementtype'
      selector: elementtype_unique_id
  ids:
    tid:
      type: integer

destination:
  plugin: entity:menu_link_content
  no_stub: true

process:
  bundle: menu_link_content
  title: nav_title

  menu_name:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: main

  'link/uri':
    -
      plugin: migration
      migration: page_node # Use different migrations here
      source: tid
    -
      plugin: generate_path

  route_name: '@route/route_name'

  ...
```

That works as expected. The page_node migration uses the same url as the navigation_main migration. But thats not what I want.
Now, I need to create different content types depending on the source "element_type_unique_id". Each row needs to fetch its data from the source CSM via HTTP GET first (using the "tid" as indicator), e.g. http://my.url.com/migrate/element?id=1234. The Response gives me all the data I want to migrate to Drupal 8 according to the elementype in the source CMS. I think I have to write a migration for every type but I don't know how and where to connect them in the migration process.

Is this possible? Thanks for your help!